# Issues with element detection on remote machine using PyAutoGUI and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, gitlab-ci-runner, pyautogui, pyscreeze

Given: PyAutoGUI and OpenCV. Their specific task is to find a particular element on the current screen by exact match. This is done by taking a screenshot of the entire screen and then searching for an image (rectangular, with clear edges) on it. If successful, the coordinates of where the match was found are returned.

The problem: Locally everything works fine; the code runs, and all desired elements are found. Apart from the local environment, there is a test machine with a GitLab runner that executes the code. When running on this machine, some elements are found with a 100% success rate, while others are not found under any conditions, regardless of the image being searched for, whether it's larger or smaller. It feels like it can't find elements associated with additional pop-up windows within the application. It's unclear what role this plays because the screenshot captures all these windows, so they should be found.

Attempts made that didn't help: Set the same resolution on both machines, converted images to the same color space, used pixel fonts to reduce noise, tried several different libraries and search methods—always failing at the same stage. Checked libraries and path variables—everything is the same.

What can be done to understand the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: It's extra work, but you might consider digging into OpenCV [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html). The link is a good Python tutorial. PyAutoGUI needs an exact pixel by pixel match. And if the region of interest has text, the fonts and the font hinting must be pixel by pixel identical. With OpenCV you can use a matching score of less than 100%.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure it out, but the main problem is that locally everything works fine, but on a remote machine with the same configurations and settings - for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: "What can be done to understand the problem and how to fix it?" -- a [mcve] would be first step. Also divide and conquer, if the screen capture works correctly, remove it from the scenario. | So, if on the remote machine you save the screenshot using some lossless codec, and run the processing on that exact same input image, you get different results on different machines?

Comment: That's a good point @DanMašek. You have to save the screenshot in a lossless format (PNG is a good choice). JPEG will absolutely not work because compression artifacts will be different for every save.

Answer (score 0):

Well, everything was solved in a rather non-trivial way. The problem was in the program under test and the settings of the test user. The point is that the UI of the program adapted to the DPI of the user's screen, and it did it only once - for the first user who logged in after rebooting, so the layout of interface elements and font thickness changed, everywhere a little bit, but as a result it led to a big difference. Even though fonts and screen resolution were standardized.
I took over this project from another developer (whose dpi was 2 times different from mine) - his DPI settings were preserved on the test machine and test profile. This was not easy to trace, as I was on the test machine under my own user with normal settings, and the tests were run using the test user.
However, @Dan Mašek's reply helped me to some extent to organize the solution approach and decompose the problem, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps you could add more details on how you fixed it to help others with a similar situation in the future.